# How do I model API response with MobX State Tree?

Tags: typescript, types, mobx-state-tree

Consider an example where I am calling a Login API which returns me an Account object. In typescript, I would normally do this.

```
const account: Account = new Account(response.data)
```

This is my current MST model

```
export const UserModel = types.model("UserModel").props({
  id: "",
  firstName: "",
  lastName: "",
  onboardingStage: types.optional(OnboardingStage, "signup"),
  roles: types.array(UserRoles),
})

export const AccountStoreModel = types.model("AccountModel").props({
  token: types.optional(types.string, ""),
  user: types.optional(UserModel, {}),
})

export interface AccountStore extends Instance<typeof AccountStoreModel> {}
```

Questions:

1. How can I return API response such that, I can access account model properties like `accountResponse.firstName`?
2. `AccountStore` interface throws these type errors

   - TS2411: Property 'token' of type 'string' is not assignable to string index type 'Function'.
   - TS2411: Property 'user' of type '{ id: string; firstName: string; lastName: string; onboardingStage: "signup"; roles: IMSTArray "parent">> & IStateTreeNode  "parent">>>; } & NonEmptyObject & IStateTreeNode...>' is not assignable to string index type 'Function'.